# How to reduce usage of memory?

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is a sample of my code

```
def normalize_3D(input):
    for i in range(input.shape[0]):
        s = tf.concat([tf.reshape(input[i, 9, 0], shape=[1, 1]),
                       tf.reshape(input[i, 9, 1], shape=[1, 1]),
                       tf.reshape(input[i, 9, 2], shape=[1, 1])], axis=1)

        output = input[i, :, :] - s
        output2 = output / tf.sqrt(tf.square(input[i, 9, 0] - input[i, 0, 0]) +
                                   tf.square(input[i, 9, 1] - input[i, 0, 1]) +
                                   tf.square(input[i, 9, 2] - input[i, 0, 2]))
        output2 = tf.reshape(output2, [1, input.shape[1], input.shape[2]])
        if i == 0:
            output3 = output2
        else:
            output3 = tf.concat([output3, output2], axis=0)

    return output3
```

like this sample I used 'for' state many times to calculate the data which has just a few batch.
However, while I'm writing my code, I noticed that it uses a lot of memory and error message came out.
Some of my predictions just showing 'nan' and after that the program is stucked.

Is there any way to reduce this kind of memory abuse when I calculate batch data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function can be expressed in a simpler and more efficient way like this:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def normalize_3D(input):
    shift = input[:, 9]
    scale = tf.norm(input[:, 9] - input[:, 0], axis=1, keepdims=True)
    output = (input - tf.expand_dims(shift, 1)) / tf.expand_dims(scale, 1)
    return output
```